# C# - Messageboxes do not display in compiled app, work in debugger

Tags: messagebox, addin-express

I've got a Windows Forms application that works as an add-in for Outlook using Add-in Express. I inserted some debugging code that throws up messageboxes with status reports, and this works fine while I'm debugging in Visual Studio, or when I install the app on my own machine.

My B.A. is trying to test the app, but when she installs it, none of the messageboxes display.

A couple routes I've been exploring:

1. She doesn't have Visual Studio
   installed on her machine. Perhaps there's something missing in the
   installation?
2. The messageboxes are called inside a utility class, so even though I
       have Windows.Forms referenced, I've seen hints online that this can
       be problematic.

I appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

[edit]

Just tried an install on a VM with no Visual Studio installed, and the messageboxes appear just fine, so it's not #1 above.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the "debugging code that throws up messageboxes"? Or, possibly related, does that code somehow rely on debugging info (e.g. from `.pdb` files) that you are not deploying to the B.A.'s machine?

Comment: In a helper class, I use the following:
public static void OpenMatterWindow(string inMatterId, bool  inNewThread = false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Properties.Settings.Default.IsDatabaseAvailable)
                {
                    inMatterId = ProperMatterId(inMatterId);
                    MessageBox.Show("In OpenMatterWindow with matterid = '{0}'", inMatterId); 
....

Comment: Sorry for the formatting - can't grok the formatting markup.